# Permissions of subdirectories on Samba

Tags: permissions, directory, samba

On a CentOS7 system I installed samba to create a share for windows clients using the following steps:

```
mkdir /samba/myShare
```

Then I definded `/samba/myShare` as my shared folder via the `smb.conf` file. After that, I did the following steps:

```
chmod 777 /samba/myShare #(drwxrwxrwx)
mkdir /samba/myShare/myFolder
chmod 774 /samba/myShare/myFolder #(drwxrwxr--)
```

Now I thought that the `myFolder` directory would be protected against changing its name or deleting it via Windows users by giving just read-permission to "other users" but that was not the case. The directory itself remained writeable. Then I was googling for it and came to the point that the directory remained writable because as a child-directory it takes the permissions from his mother-directory, which is `/samba/myShare` in my case. But now comes the strange thing that confuses me a lot:

- When I do a `chmod 773 /samba/myShare/myFolder` (`drwxrwx-wx`) I am not able to change or delete the directory itself via Windows anymore. Could someone please explain what this is all about?
- Why can I delete and change `myfolder` via the Windows client when I set the permissions to `drwxrwxr--` and cannot delete or change it when I set the permissions to `drwxrwx-wx`?

The entry in the `smb.conf` may be helpful:

```
[global]
workgroup = SAMBA
security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
printing = cups
printcap name = cups
load printers = yes
cups options = raw
map to guest = bad user`
`[myShare]
comment = myShare
path = /samba/myShare
public = yes
writeable = yes
```

Oh yeah: I know that setting 777-permissions is not very common but this was just for testing.

Comment: Okay, I added it. In the [global] section I just added the **map to guest = bad user** setting manually, the rest I left in its default settings.